# How to get tail -f results using an asynchronous script?

Tags: php, jquery, bash

I have a PHP page in which I want to display the newly added lines to a log file during last 3 seconds. At the moment, I am using jQuery get function to run a PHP file, which in turns runs shell_exec.

I am using these scripts:

jQuery on main page:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('tailer.php', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}, 3000);
```

tailer.php:

```
<?php
    $result = shell_exec("timeout 3s sudo tail -f log.txt");
    echo $result;
?>
```

The problem is that when I run the tailer.php script from command line, it returns the lines as expected. But when running the same file using a browser, it doesn't stop loading and return nothing. So the script in the main PHP page does not alert anything.

I was able to narrow down the issue and noticed that when removing -f switch from tail command, everything is fine. The issue is only with -f switch. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly why but the problem resolved after moving `sudo` to before `timeout` command. The final working tailer.php contents look like this:

```
<?php
    $result = shell_exec("sudo timeout 3s tail -f log.txt");
    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I first started writing web apps, I used this technique as well, JS - PHP - BASH. It's not the best way, you should consider using PHP (or Node) to handle all the server side stuff that bash is doing now.

I can't remember what the reason for the problem you have (and I had) is, but this solution worked for me:

In your tailer.php, use this code:

```
<?php
 exec("/bin/bash -c 'tail -f log.txt'", $output, $return_var);
 echo $output
?>
```

$return_var is the exit status of the bash script, and I think $output will hold the return values from the bash script.

Can you show me the response from the AJAX (found in the dev-tools Network section).

If there's nothing, can you switch `echo $output` for `echo $return_var` so we can see if the bash cmd of exiting true or false.

:-)

Comment: Thank you, I changed my PHP script to <?php
 $result = shell_exec("/bin/bash -c 'tailer.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &'");
 echo $result;
?>. Now when running intermediate.php, it returns nothing. When I run the tailer.sh from command line, it returns the lines as expected. I tested removing "  > /dev/null 2>&1" part as well. This time, the intermediate.php does not stop loading!

Comment: That's not the code I wrote though ;-) - don't set the exec command as a value to the $result var. Just use the $output var. I had edited the original post, maybe you saw the old answer? Sorry!

Comment: Yes :) I saw your first reply. I tested the new code too. But the result was the same. To see whats going in the background, I ran intermediate.php from command line to see the errors. The error was "PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in tailer.sh". So I used foreach($output as $line) {
  echo $line;
 } instead of simply echoing the $output. This time, it returned nothing!

Comment: Shoot, I think I made a mistake, try removing the `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Yeah I did that. It is now printing out the results when running the PHP file from command line. But when running from browser, it doesn't stop loading the page and shows nothing :(

Comment: Mmmm.. Are you able to share the full PHP and bash scripts. Sometimes a bash script can not return anything, causing the exec command to permanently wait for it. If you can share the full scripts, I can suggest some debugging code to help us.

Comment: Sure, I made some changes to the codes and now I am running the shell_exec directly from PHP instead of bash file for simplicity. I updated the main question with full scripts.

Comment: OK, see my edit, hopefully it works :-) Also, make sure the log file has 777 permissions

Answer (score 0):

### First question

PHP engine executes php code when request comes and returns the output of php code when this execution is finished (You can still manually flush the output buffer by using `flush` function). It seems like your php code is blocked(waiting) when executing shell script.

### Second question

I would suggest write a script running background just to put file changes into Redis and use ajax to query Redis for update. If you want pure php code, I can't find a resonable solution(PHP is not the best tool for long connection).

By the way, multiple shell script will be executed at the same time when multiple connection are established, which is not sufficient for such a file watch job.